# Rerun second option select php script when cookie gets updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to write a script where the option list for the second option select is depended on the selected value of the first option select.
 Basically, the option list of the **first option** select contains the **name** of the php table. The script that I have below stores the option selected in a cookie called `account_list`. The php code in the **second option** select reads the cookie as table name and performs a query. However, when selecting another option in the first option select, the cookie gets **updated** but the php script in the second option select doesn't get **update/rerun**.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-addon gi gi-parking"></span>
  <select id="account_list" class="form-control custom-select" name="account_list" 
     onchange="getAccount(this)"/>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <span class="input-group-addon gi gi-industrial-zone"></span>
  <select id="property_class" class="form-control custom-select" name="order_list"/>
    <?php
      $list = $_COOKIE['account_list'];
      $o_list = $DB_CON_C->query("SELECT contract_number FROM `".$list."`
               ORDER BY `id` DESC");
      $data_row = '<option value="" disabled>Choose an order</option>';
      if($o_list !== false) {
        foreach($o_list as $row) {
          $data_row .= '<option>'.$row['contract_number'].'</option>'."\n";
        }
      }
      unset($row);
      echo $data_row;
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<script>
  function createCookie(name, value, days){
    var expires;
    if (days){
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
      expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
  }
</script>
<script>
  function getAccount(account_list){
    var list = $(account_list).val();
    createCookie("account_list", list, "1");
  }
</script>
```

Anyone knows what do I need to do to make the php script works when the cookie gets updated? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a dependent dropdown like this? [link](http://demos.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly all I wanted to do.

Comment: You can use `jquery and ajax` to do this in a simple way. Since you are using `cookie` it will be unable to show your updated code untill you don't refresh the page. So I'll suggest you to go with `ajax`.